# ArrayList initializing

Tags: java, arraylist

Hey guys I just have a quick question about initializing an arraylist

This is just a small piece of code I'm doing

```
public class OrderManager {
    ArrayList<Order>orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    public OrderManager() {

    }

    public OrderManager(ArrayList<Order> orders) {
        orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    }
```

using a variable orders, and then declaring `orders = new` correct? Or is this going to be two different instances and when I try to add things to it its not going to work?

Or since OrderManager is going to take an arraylist does it even make sense?

I haven't tested it yet, I just started writing this code and have ran into this problem before where I couldn't add to the list properly and believe it was because of a error similar to this just checking to try and get it right to start with.

Comment: You are reassigning it in the constructor, so it makes no difference (unless it's in multithreaded code). Also, see below comment.

Comment: You probably should use `this.orders = orders` in your second constructor if you want `OrderManager` to store passed list of orders.

Comment: Ok, so when I put an addOrder method in this same code would it be better to use this.orders.add, or would that not make sense?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one has answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class OrderManager {
    private ArrayList<Order>orders;
    public OrderManager() {
      this(new ArrayList<>());//call constructor
    }

    public OrderManager(ArrayList<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
  .
  .
   //more methods here for example getters and/or setters for orders
}
```

This is the proper way. Also consider using `List` rather than `ArrayList` cause in future if you want not to be `ArrayList` and for example be `LinkedList` you don't have to modify this class. Programming to an interface concept.

So your class would look like:

```
    public class OrderManager {
        private final List<Order>orders;

        public OrderManager() {
          this(new ArrayList<>());//call constructor or doing nothing is another option
        }

        public OrderManager(List<Order> orders) {
            this.orders = orders;
        }


       public List<Order> getOrders(){
           return orders;
       }    

       public void addOrder(Order order){
            orders.add(order);
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are currently doing is assigning a `new`, empty `ArrayList` instead of taking the one given.

You should either do this:

```
public class OrderManager {
    private final List<Order> orders;

    public OrderManager() {
        orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    }

    public OrderManager(final List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
```

Which will take the reference to the `List` passed into the constructor. Changes to the `List` from *outside* the class will affect the `List` inside the class.

A more common way is to make a "defensive copy" using the copy constructor

```
public class OrderManager {
    private final List<Order>orders;

    public OrderManager() {
        orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    }

    public OrderManager(final List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = new ArrayList<Order>(orders);
    }
```

Now the class has a copy of the `List` passed in so it will be independent of the original `List`.

Comment: i don't get the point.. to store the variable as a `List` if you are always creating statically as an `ArrayList`

Comment: From my experience, it is usually better to declare a pre-condition in the constructor, such as *`orders` is a fresh instance / no outside references are kept*, than bothering to clone / copy the given arguments defensively.

Comment: @nachokk Because if I decide to change that I only need to change the assignment. If you used an `ArrayList` then you would need to change that everywhere.

Comment: @afsantos That doesn't provide any guarantees against stupidity whereas a defensive copy does. There is much stupidity in the world...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Agreed. That's just an approach to *solve* the problem. Another would be to let stupidity meet the bugs it creates. Generally, defensive copies would work best on public / API level, whereas private / package-private levels assume that you know what you're doing. In the end, it's little more than a matter of habits and style.

Answer (score 0):

Your second constructor is wrong.

It should be:

```
public OrderManager(ArrayList<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
```

Constructor is what used to create a new object and initialize its class variables.

When you use `new` you are calling a class constructor.

There are cases when one constructor can be called from another. It's done when the calling constructor initializes a larger set of variables and uses other constructor to initialize a sub-set (so not to repeat the same code).  At such cases you use `this` with a proper signature.